# Querying the user list from the database

Tags: users

There is a need from a different team in our organization to provide a periodic export of users, roles, and users-roles relationship data in a certain [Aveksa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aveksa)-specific format.

Where (which table(s)) are the list of Drupal 8 users and roles stored in Drupal database? I've looked at all the tables listed in the schema and examined their records, and could not find anything that resembled user/roles data.

I figure querying the database is the way to go rather than looking at the /admin/people section of Drupal and scraping the data from there.

Comment: There is a user__roles table..

Answer (score 3):

If you're set on scraping this out of the database, you could try looking at the `user__roles` table that Kevin mentioned in his comment above:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user__roles;
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------+
| bundle | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | langcode | delta | roles_target_id |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------+
| user   |       0 |         1 |           1 | en       |     0 | administrator   |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But since this is Drupal, you have other methods at your disposal.

For example, you could create a View of users and roles, and then use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to export.

This module also exposes a drush command that can execute the view (interactively, or via scheduled jobs from the system crontab) and save its results to a file.

`drush views-data-export [view-name] [display-id] [output-file]`